# dragging browser tabs to new window moves old window

Tags: macos, google-chrome, web-browser, tabs

Happens periodically with chrome, not sure about other browsers.

If I have a window with multiple tabs and drag one of them either to create a new window or place it in another, usually to my other monitor, the original window gets moved as well, typically about half of the distance.

This just started happening out of now where, the only thing that has changed on my computer recently was I reinstalled chrome after having flash issues with video.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is not a OS X error, and is instead a browser error, you should submit it like this: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?hl=en

Hope this helps!

(Note that this bug is nonexistent on Safari, latest beta)